# How do I get FindMinimum to give me the right answer the first time I call it?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize the Chi Square error on a complex function.  The first time I run **FindMinimum** I get an answer which is close to the global minimum, the second time I run it, with the results from the first pass, I get a better answer (note the results below).  How do I do this in a single pass?

```
result = FindMinimum[{chiSquared[ber, btm, dsr, dcd], 
   0 < ber && 0 < btm && 0 < dsr && 0 < dcd}, {{ber, 1.}, {btm, 
    10^10}, {dsr, 1.}, {dcd, 1000}}]

Out[402]= {1603.9032996720166, {ber -> 0.30175546158546906, 
  btm -> 8.984265873668348*^9, dsr -> 3.114204410911019, 
  dcd -> 1100.9245439266256}}

In[403]:= result = 
 FindMinimum[{chiSquared[ber, btm, dsr, dcd]}, {{ber, 
    OptionValue[result[[2]], ber]}, {btm, 
    OptionValue[result[[2]], btm]}, 
       {dsr, OptionValue[result[[2]], dsr]}, {dcd, 
    OptionValue[result[[2]], dcd]}}]

Out[403]= {1558.845892206124, {ber -> 0.4090451007924997, 
  btm -> 1.1343566072120678*^10, dsr -> 3.4512578697898606, 
  dcd -> 928.6070747021281}}
```

Comment: Maybe by increasing the value of the option `MaxIterations`?

Comment: I went up to 500.  Do you think giving it more will help?

Comment: Well, running `FindMinimum` twice should roughly correspond to doubling `MaxIterations` or not? (Well there are optimization tools that carry on a "history" of the optimization process. And deleting this history can sometimes help if the algorithm gets stuck.)

Comment: Setting MaxIterations->10000 didn't change the result.  I also set WorkingPrecision, AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal to 30.  No change to the result.  But, for some reason, running it twice seems to find the global minimum.

Comment: Erm. You removed the inequality constraints in the second call right? So it is not surprising that the "solution" changes. It is probably not the solution of the original problem! Hm. On the other hand, the constraint do not seem to be active in the first solution...

Comment: I can confirm that the constraints appear to give a different answer.  It would appear that the first time I call **FindMinimum**, it gets me in the neighborhood, but the constraints prevent an accurate solution.  The second time I call it without constraints, it's able to find a precise answer.

Comment: Hm. I think that `FindMinimum` uses a interior point method (a.k.a. barrier method) which leads to slightly perturbed solutions. They should however not be _that_ much perturbed...